# Facebook graph api where location equals

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to search pages which location city equals to xyz.
For example find page Guiness in city = Wroclaw, it looks like this:

```
/search?q=Guiness&type=page&city=Wroclaw
```

But it doesn't work ?!
I tried many different ways.
I think the problem is in that the location is complex type, but I can't find in documentation how to search by complex type :(.

Hope help will came soon.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clearly documented what is possible with the `/search` endpoint:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#search

You can't use other parameters than outlined there. Either this would be

```
/search?q=Guiness%20Wroclaw&type=page&fields=id,name,location
```

or search for a place with center coordinate and a distance:

```
/search?q=Guiness&type=place&center=52.231804,21.007973&distance=5000
```